# Why do some non-towered airports have class E airspace from the surface up?

Tags: faa, airspace, non-towered-airport

I've noticed that when it comes to non-towered airports, some are in class G airspace and others have class E airspace starting from the surface. At first I thought the airports with class E at the surface might be in that configuration because they have precision approaches, but then I found exceptions where the airport has class G at the surface along with a precision approach. Is there a particular reason some non-towered airports are in class E while other are in class G?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why a relatively large, busy airport like CVO is not Class E to the surface.  Surely all the required conditions are met-- or, maybe not...

Answer (score 13):

This answer is specific to the United States (heck, I don't know if this is an even an issue elsewhere in the world).

The airspace classification actually has nothing to do with whether or not a particular airport has a precision approach. It is based on two factors: communications capability and weather observations.

For a non-towered airport to have Class E (surface) airspace, ATC must have communications capability with aircraft down to the runway surface. Second, weather observations must be provided by a Federally certificated observer and/or Federally commissioned weather observing system. Reference: [FAA JO 7400.2K](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.2K_w_Chg1_dtd_7-24-14.pdf), paragraphs 18-1-1 and 18-1-2.

If one (or both) of these conditions are not satisfied, the surface airspace will be class G with a class E floor of 700 ft. AGL if there is an instrument approach into the airport and 1200 ft. AGL if not.

Now, here's a twist: if the airport has a part-time control tower, the airspace may become Class G when the tower is closed, even if both communication and weather reporting requirements are satisfied. Be sure to check the Chart Supplement (fka A/FD).

Comment: How can you confirm if a non-towered airport is E versus G? Does the FAA maintain a list?

Comment: This information is depicted on VFR charts. If you look in the chart legend, there is a notation that states 'Class E Airspace exists at 1200' AGL unless otherwise designated as shown above.' This means that an airport's airspace will be Class G unless there are graphics that indicate Class E starts at a lower altitude (i.e., 700' AGL or at the surface).

Comment: Can you give a reference for your last point re: after control tower hours? AIM 3-2-5 says "when the control tower closes, the airspace revert back to either class E, or a combination of Class G and class E depending on the chart depiction and the description in the A/FD" but mentions nothing about weather observations.

Comment: @DavidDeVine, the last point was poorly worded as it is not a universal condition. I've updated it accordingly. Classification as controlled airspace (i.e. Class B, C, D, or E) is not automatic, thus an airport with a part-time control tower may (or may not) be controlled airspace when the tower is closed, even if the conditions for Class E surface area are met.

Comment: @DavidDeVine -- it's interesting that AIM 3-2-5 is no longer worded that way, there is no reference to "a combination".  There was a major rewrite in 2016, I wonder if your reference came from before 2016?  I guess the "combination" idea was in reference to the *vertical* structure of the airspace, i.e. Class G up to (normally) 700' or 1200' AGL and then Class E above-- as opposed to the alternative situation of Class E all the way down to the surface--

Comment: It's also interesting that *as long as the airspace has no surface-level Class E extension*, there is no way to tell from the chart alone which of these two possibilities is the case for part-time Class D airspace.  *You have to check the Chart Supplement* to see whether the surface-level airspace converts to G, or to E, when the tower is closed.