# When is Class Delta Airspace not Class Delta?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, class-d-airspace

Although there could be many examples, I'm using the KLCQ airport in this case. This is how the airspace stands:

[image: KLCQ AIRSPACE]

In the CHART Supplement, it is mentioned that it's a "Class D svc other times class E".

[image: KLCQ AFD]

I called the Airport Manager and he confirmed saying "Yes, we're a Class D during the time tower is in service. Other than that, it's Class E".

**Questions:**

1) Why does this airport not have a dashed blue circle like a normal Class D?

2) Since it's inside a Class E Transition airspace, shouldn't the airspace be Class G up to 700' AGL when tower is not in operation?

3) What is primarily required for an airport to actually be designated as a Class D airport - x amount of traffic, x amount services, x amount of weather reporting capabilities?

Why should this matter?

1. Weather minimums
2. Communications with ATC during arrival/departure
3. Etc.

Comment: Since you confirmed it is class D airspace it needs to have a blue dashed line.  If it goes to class E airspace it may also require a magenta dashed line.  Looks like you found an error.  Report it. There is a way to report discrepancies on the sectional chart informational tab.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of another question - Uncontrolled airspace around a towered airport.  http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/can-an-aerodrome-in-class-g-airspace-be-controlled/29838#29838

Comment: I suspect the chart update is lagging behind the airspace changes there. See [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29838/62) for some related information.

Comment: Class D need a tower and alternate airport-approved weather reporting

Comment: I just pulled this airport up in ForeFlight and the blue dashed line is there, inside the magenta Class E boundary. So the charts have caught up with the change in airspace classification.

Comment: @wbeard52 -- just for the record-- (a bit late!) -- a dashed magenta line is not used in the depiction of airports that are Class D and revert to surface-level Class E when the tower is closed.  There is a dashed blue line, and a notation on the chart to "See Notams/Chart supplement for eff hrs Class D" or something to that effect.

Comment: @wbeard52 -- (ctd) --   A pilot seeing this notation on the VFR sectional chart-- at least in the case of an airport lacking any surface-level Class E *extension*, since airports with such *extensions* are treated slightly differently-- has *no way to know without checking the Chart Supplement or other resources* whether the airspace becomes G or surface-level Class E when the tower is closed.  There are many examples of each possibility.

Comment: @wbeard52 -- (ctd) --Re "has no way to know without checking the Chart Supplement or other resources" -- I'm considering submitting a suggestion for a new chart notation system that would change this situation.