# In the US, are there any operational control towers located in surface-level Class E airspace or in Class G airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, airspace, class-e-airspace

(This question pertains to the airspace of the United States.)

[FAR 91.126](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.126) gives some general rules for operating at or near airports in Class G airspace, and [FAR 91.127](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.127) gives some general rules for operating at or near airports in Class E airspace.

Section (d) of 91.126 and section (c) of 91.127 pertain specifically to operations at airports with operational control towers.

**a) This seems to beg the question, are there any operational control towers located in surface-level Class E airspace or in Class G airspace?**

b) Were there ever?  (Counting from the September 16, 1993 "alphabet" airspace re-organization onward.)

c) If "no" to a and b, then what is a practical example of how a pilot's behavior might be altered by the need to comply with 91.126(d) or 91.127(c)?  After all, it appears that generally speaking, it is not possible to get within 4 nautical miles of an airport with an operational control tower, at 2500' AGL or below, without entering Class D (or higher) airspace.

Comment: [This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29838/54557) indicates that LCQ, a towered airport, used to be in Class G airspace.

Comment: @randomhead -- good find-- and I see that the airspace has now become Class D there.

Comment: A 2016 comment under this answer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29824/34686 references KTME as another example of a towered airport in Class G airspace; it too is Class D now.

Comment: Back to LCQ, [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30426/54557) makes it sound like the tower was perhaps newly installed and the chart hadn't been updated—it was actually Class D when the tower was operational. Perhaps.

Comment: And my discussion with Dean F. under [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/78694/54557) led me to [a document describing a *temporary* ATCT](https://web.archive.org/web/20161103000909if_/http://www.delandairport.com:80/sites/delandairport/files/file/file/2016_atc_instructions_2.pdf), which would turn the airspace from Class G to Class E.

Comment: @randomhead -- I wonder why they didn't just go ahead and make it temporary Class D --more complex to accomplish?

Comment: @randomhead -- re document cited in your last comment-- I'm not sure whether they really did make it surface-level Class E-- see my comments under TrevorJohn answer--

Comment: @randomhead -- I see room for a new ASE question here, asking if they really did make the airspace at DeLand be temporary surface-level Class E, or not.  But, enough for today-- maybe someone else will wish to ask it--

Comment: @randomhead-- have now deleted those comments, but basically, they just explained that I confirmed the airspace at DeLand was normally class G (up to 700') back in 2016, and I did a NOTAM search that turned up a reference to the temporary control tower but no reference to a change in airspace status.

Comment: Nearly ten days after this string of questions was started, it finally occurs to me to ask, if the airport is in Class G airspace (i.e. that's what the airspace is at ground level), but the aircraft is in overlying Class E airspace, at that instant in time, which rules govern the aircraft, 91.126 or 91.127?  In other words, does the word "in" in the title of the regulations refer to the word "airport", or to the word "operating"?

Comment: I read it the former way, hence my conclusion that the existence 91.127c kind of implies that the FAA envisioned that there were, or might be, towered airports in surface-level Class E airspace. But I can see that it is not completely unambiguous, and some of the answers might have been written from the viewpoint that the purpose of 91.127 might be to govern aircraft coming in to land at an airport located in (surface-level) Class G airspace, while those aircraft are still in the overlying Class E airspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a handful of towers still in surface Class E/G airspace. They're rare, but they do exist and are something to watch out for during preflight planning.

As of April 2021, here's the airports I know of:

- [KJYO](https://skyvector.com/airport/JYO/Leesburg-Exec-Airport) - Leesburg, VA
- [KPCA](https://skyvector.com/airport/PCA/Picacho-Arng-Heliport) - Picacho ARNG, AZ
- [KTNX](https://skyvector.com/airport/TNX/Tonopah-Test-Range-Airport) - Tonopah Test Range, NV (inside restricted airspace)

I wouldn't be surprised if there's others I missed, these aren't really cataloged anywhere.

Many of these do eventually become proper Class D airports once they have proper weather reporting capability. For example, [KTRK](https://skyvector.com/airport/TRK/Truckee-Tahoe-Airport) (Truckee, CA) was an infamous one on the west coast that [just got its Class D ring in 2017](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2017/12/19/2017-27209/amendment-of-class-d-and-class-e-airspace-truckee-ca).

You'll also see temporary towers pop up via NOTAM for special events. These NOTAMs don't change the airspace designation, since changes to airspace need to go through the formal rulemaking process.

Comment: Since the question references surface-level Class E airspace, you might want to clarify that first sentence refers to "Class G airspace at the surface  (with Class E airspace above)"-- *if* that's what you meant.  On the other hand, maybe you did mean Class G airspace *or* surface-level Class E airspace, though no examples were provided of the latter.

Answer (score 3):

At areas where a local increase in traffic density occurs, a temporary tower may be installed.  This may be at an uncontrolled airport which may be in class E, or even Class G airspace. By definition, whereas class G is uncontrolled airspace, adding a control tower does require a Notice to Airmen alerting to the change in airspace and the requirement of the control tower at that location.  This information will be cited by NOTAM and announced on ATIS and airport advisories.

Temporary towers are typically erected at airshow events, or places where a sudden local increase in traffic has occurred, such as during firefighting operations.

Controllers will be typically FAA controllers, or sometimes retired controllers on a contract basis, or operating with a contractor, in a mobile airport traffic control tower (MATCT).  They will be monitoring the common traffic advisory frequency for aircraft that arrive without knowing that a tower is in operation, and in most cases, will quickly advise the arriving aircraft of the tower operation.

It's a pilot (legal) responsibility to become familiar with all aspects of the flight, including checking all NOTAMs.  Temporary towers are NOTAM'd prior to going into operation, typically a day or two prior if the advance notice is there, so there's little excuse for blundering into a temporary tower and not knowing its there.

There are towers in Class G airspace, or towers that lack Class D airspace, because the tower or airport lacks the weather reporting capability, which is a requirement for establishing Class D airspace.  As the original poster noted in his question, 14 CFR 91.126 covers Class G airspace, and 91.126(d), in the context of Class G airspace, addresses a requirement to establish communication with a control tower prior to 4 nm from the airport.

https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=b7ed8006f4088b8259a4bd7380008c24&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1126&rgn=div8

Comment: Good answer; phrase "adding a control tower does require a Notice to Airmen alerting to the change in airspace" seems to imply that the airspace may be temporarily designated as Class D (or surface-level Class E?) in the case of a temporary tower; if so you might want to state that more explicitly. I'm not clear as to whether temporary towers are sometimes, usually, always, rarely, or never accompanied by temporary designation of Class D (or surface-level Class E) airspace-- if rarely or never, might be a way to phrase that w/o mentioning a "change in airspace"-- –

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, there is a tower in G (with E above), you just can't fly there

Surface-level controlled (alphabet) airspace isn't allowed to overlap special-use (R-area) airspace, as can be noted from the situation at [Creech AFB](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35420/3825).  This means that the tower (Silverbow Tower) at Tonopah Test Range (KTNX) isn't in controlled airspace as the airport is within the bounds of the Nellis Range Complex.  Of course, that also means that it doesn't see civil traffic, only USAF "black" operations, JANET flights on behalf of the DoD, and the occasional emergency knockoff from normal Nellis Range operations I'm sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your premise. The intro section of [the wiki article on US airspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class_%28United_States%29) says that "airspace class" (A/B/C/D/E/G) and "airspace category" (unrestricted, restricted, prohibited) are *not* mutually exclusive. The airspace designers may have *chosen* to not allow the Creech Class D to enter R-4806W, but the airspace is still controlled (Class E). No?

Comment: @randomhead -- you do make a good point in that the presence of SUA doesn't affect the normal E/G split at 1200' AGL, amended the answer to clarify that that isn't affected